# Slow query with where like, order by and limit

Tags: mysql

I'm having an issue with the speed of a query I wan't to do.
The rooms table has 2685588 rows, and the room_active has less than 100, but it isn't slow with normal queries.

The query is:

```
SELECT rooms.*, room_active.active_users
FROM rooms LEFT JOIN room_active ON (room_active.roomid = rooms.id) 
WHERE caption LIKE '%room%' ORDER BY room_active.active_users LIMIT 50
```

**Runtime**: 4.3s

It takes more than 5 seconds to execute when it should take less than one like does this one:

```
SELECT rooms.*, room_active.active_users 
FROM rooms LEFT JOIN room_active ON (room_active.roomid = rooms.id) 
WHERE caption LIKE '%room%' LIMIT 50
```

**Runtime**: 0.3s

The describe for the first query is this:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+----------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys  | key     | key_len | ref            | rows    | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+----------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | rooms       | ALL    | NULL           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL           | 2210576 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | room_active | eq_ref | PRIMARY,roomid | PRIMARY | 4       | xukys.rooms.id |       1 | NULL                                         |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+----------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Indexes:

```
+-------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| rooms |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | id          | A         |     2210613 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          1 | owner       |            1 | owner       | A         |     2210613 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          1 | roomtype    |            1 | roomtype    | A         |          18 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          1 | caption     |            1 | caption     | A         |     2210613 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          1 | category    |            1 | category    | A         |          18 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          1 | users_now   |            1 | users_now   | A         |          18 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          1 | tags        |            1 | tags        | A         |          18 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          1 | users_max   |            1 | users_max   | A         |          18 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          1 | description |            1 | description | A         |      368435 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          1 | state       |            1 | state       | A         |          18 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          1 | model_name  |            1 | model_name  | A         |          18 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          1 | public_ccts |            1 | public_ccts | A         |          18 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          1 | score       |            1 | score       | A         |          18 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          1 | password    |            1 | password    | A         |          18 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          1 | icon_bg     |            1 | icon_bg     | A         |         954 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          1 | icon_fg     |            1 | icon_fg     | A         |          18 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          1 | badge_id    |            1 | badge_id    | A         |         804 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name     | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| room_active |          0 | PRIMARY      |            1 | roomid       | A             |         116 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| room_active |          0 | roomid       |            1 | roomid       | A         |         116 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| room_active |          1 | active_users |            1 | active_users | A         |          29 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: Try a smaller result set.. The `ORDER BY` is killing your performance.

Comment: Where are you indexes? Adding an index on room_active.active_users should help the ordering

Comment: The table room_active has 2 columns, roomid and active_users wich both are indexed separately. Also are the columns used in this query from rooms table.

Comment: Try creating a compound index on table room_active `(active_users, roomid)`. And you can create index on caption or take advantage of it but you are using `%` in start which does not allow optimizer to use index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` is removing the advantage of `LIMIT 50` because to be able to order by the 50 first elements he has to fetch all the records.

maybe if you tell us what exactly you want, we can help with the query. For example do you really need to do a LEFT JOIN and get all the rooms who don't have a room_active ?

not sure if it helps, but try this one

```
SELECT rooms.*, room_active.active_users 
FROM room_active ra JOIN rooms r ON (room_active.roomid = rooms.id) 
WHERE r.caption LIKE '%room%' ORDER BY ra.active_users LIMIT 50
```

It will ignore the rooms that don't have a room_active, reducing the fetched records

Comment: I need to get 50 rooms ordered by the amount of users inside it (room_active), thats what is for the LEFT JOIN. If the room has users inside it will be in that table, and will be ordered.

Comment: and room_active always has a room id so a JOIN and a LEFT JOIN are the same ?

Comment: Not always, just when the room has an user inside. That's why I use LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Thanks for explaining me that it would fetch all records. Instead of doing the query in MySQL I did a function in my application that does the same.

Answer (score 0):

## 1 you might want a index perhaps on the order?

## 2 You don't need %room% do you? room% would be faster, your effectivly searching all files if you don't

## 3 don't left join if you can and only want active? instead inner join because it will require less joins (it doesnt join the ones that are null)

## 4 dont select .* unless needed?

## 5. Maybe you can use a differnt function such as Contains if you are using oracle

## 6. Put a index on caption its being mass searched thats probably the problem

Comment: I have updated the question with the indexes I have, as you can see all used in the query are indexed. I do need %room%, room% is faster but I need the first one. With INNER JOIN no record show. I do need all columns in the rooms table for my application.

Comment: would like '____' be pratical instead?[The underscore allows any character for that particular slot, if it has varying prefixes that solution may not be viable; you could also try to make a materialzed view if you are using oracle, that could bring your results down to 50-500ms, another solution may be to normalize the query so that no join is required; one of the problems is likely that it is ordering all 2000000 of the results before it limits them, a pretty substantial impact on performance

Answer (score 0):

Follow following steps and check performance.

1. Create index on field 'caption' for its first 4 characters and on 'active_users'.
2. Instead of "rooms.*", select fields explicitly.
3. Use "caption LIKE 'room%'" instead of "caption LIKE '%room%'".

If this still slow, you should create a view for your joined query and then perform simple select statement on your view.

Comment: The column caption already has an index, pleas see the question. I need all fields, this may cause some ms of delay not 4 secs... I need to use %room% for my application.